# Making Help Desk System: Using Custom List to View Tickets and Close Tickets

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

I am trying to create a custom list that allows me to **Click** on the Title to go to the view of the ticket.

I am also trying to make it more easily editable. I would like to have a pop-up appear if I **click** the check, but that's a little ambitious for what I need to do right now, so I would be okay with another link that would take me to the ticket's edit window.

Another very important feature is that it creates this capability for future tickets. Is there anyway to link these features or calculate them in the columns so that it applies to all tickets created?

Comment: Why are you needing a custom list for this? SharePoint provides Issue Tracking list that do exactly what you want already. Title links to the form view. Add the Edit column for links to the edit form.

Comment: My SharePoint Admin gave me a link with a weak tracking system installed as my template and I was trying to figure out how to make it work. Thank you, the Issues Tracking works a million times better and will be what I use.

Using the issue tracker, is there anyway to manipulate the tracker so that the "comments" field becomes required when you change a ticket from "active" to "closed"?

Comment: Yes, just change the column to required. I've submitted an answer for you to approve. ;)

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Issue Tracking app for SharePoint 2013. For 2010, create an Issue Tracking list.

References: http://www.lynda.com/articles/sharepoint-issue-tracking-app

http://techwirenews.com/2012/09/29/using-issue-tracking-in-sharepoint-2010/